# how to check the SD card size before mounted and do not require root

Tags: python, linux, bash

I want to check the SD card size in bash or python. Right now I know `df` can check it when the SD card is mounted or `fdisk -l` if root is available.

But I want to know how to check the SD card size without requiring mounting the card to the file system or requiring the root permission? For example, if the SD card is not mounted and I issue `df -h /dev/sdc`, this will return a wrong size. In python, `os.statvfs` this function returns the same content as well. I search on stack overflow but did not find a solution yet.

Comment: This is perhaps more a [unix.se] question than a StackOverflow one. That said, if you're only targeting Linux, I'd consider checking `/proc/partitions`, or `/sys/class/block/*/size`. That said, if your kernel restricts unprivileged access to that information, those restrictions are liable to be *intentional*, which would make the availability of any workaround a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the `lsblk -l` can do the job. It tells the total size of the partitions.